# XML vs Аннотации

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, java

На данный момент для конфигурации Hibernate, Sprint, etc. можно использовать как XML конфиги, так и аннотации. Скорее всего спрашивать "Что лучше?" бессмысленно, дабы не разводить холиваров, поэтому спрошу следующее:

Какой метод используете вы и почему? Какие преимущества и недостатки есть у этих методов?

Пока, почитав пару рассуждений, склоняюсь к аннотациям.

Answer (score 5):

Я бы "развел" варианты так:

1. Если требуется быстрая "поделушка" без нестандартных извращений, то тогда естественно аннотации
2. Если в прожекте много нестандартных фишек, то лучше уйти от аннотаций

Comment: Что значит "нестандартных фишек"?

Comment: Так всё, таки, те 2 человека которые заплюсовали, объясните мне какие "нестандартные" фишки можно сделать на xml?

Answer (score 2):

А я все же склоняюсь к XML. Самое главное для меня(это как и по WEB-программированию) это "мясо отдельно, кости отдельно". Т.е. Удобнее когда стили прописаны в отдельном файле- не захламляют основной код , да и корректировать легче.

Так же и с hibernate. Тебе не надо открывать файл и сетами и гетами для изменения,допустим, названия таблицы. Ты открываешь .xml и правишь там.

Да и xml универсальный стандарт разметок.

Comment: тогда сделаем вывод, все зависит от проекта и разработчика. аннотации берут скоростью разработки, хмл - удобством структурирования.

Answer (score 2):

[[@delphist007](/users/8287/delphist007)](/users/8287/delphist007), поробуйте изменить данные маппинга не имея исходников, самый очевидный плюс xml. А так да, т.к. аннотации находятся ближе к jvm - то нет необходимости считывать и парсить внешние файлы -> прирост производительности (хотя кого я обманываю, она там почти незаметна, если вообще есть)

Answer (score 0):

При использовании XML не надо перекомпилировать.

Comment: Не является большой проблемой при использовании Java, особенно при инкрементальной компоновке.

Comment: Но, war файл пересобрать-таки придётся.

Answer (score 0):

Где-то читал, что лучше пользоваться аннотациями. Если я не ошибаюсь, в случаи, если аннотацию нужно изменить, но перекомпиливать проект не хочется - создаем xml. Аннотация в этом случаи игнорируется. Но каши не избежать :)

Comment: В том то и дело, все пишут, что лучше, но никто не объясняет почему. А на слово просто так не хочется верить, я привык получать обоснованные ответы.

Comment: http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/07/spring-dependency-injection-styles-why-i-love-java-based-configuration/ вот здесь читал

Answer (score 0):

Да здравствуют аннотации!

Более простого и понятного способа работать со спрингом не сложно даже представить.

Во первых используя аннотации, Вы убираете проблему огромных xml  фалов. 
Во вторых делаете код более целостным, например в контроллере сразу понятно что метод замаплен на конкретный запрос ит.д.
И так еще раз Да здравствуют аннотации!

Answer (score 0):

Я использую XML потому, что только начинаю работать со Spring и еще не пришел к тому что надо сокращать размер файла конфигурации.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko так и скажите, что ответ даже не прочитали :)

Comment: @D-side почему же, прочитал. только мне показалось, что бОльшая часть - именно комментарий )